# What happen in background memory point of view when we move one branch to another branch of same project in git...?

Tags: git, github, commit, checkout

What happen in background memory point of view when we move one branch to another branch of same project in git, Where the commit store???

Comment: Please include an example scenario. It's not clear what "move one branch" means. Example commits and commands would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you *move* a branch to another, there's no new revision created. Only the pointer to the revision (aka, *the branch*, a file inside the .git directory, aka *the repo*) is renamed, but the content of the object (the file) does *not* change.

Comment: content of object not change...? do you mean files of the branch remain same ?

Comment: Sure... when you move a branch (say, `git branch -m foo bar`) there is no no revision created. Only a little file inside .git is renamed.